# Unable to login Facebook in development mode - IOS Swift 5

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, swift5

Integrated FacebookSDK in my app and submitted for approval. I need to test Facebook Login in development mode before going into live.

So when I tried to login user development mode Facebook page is showing the following error "App Not setup: This app is still in development mode and you don't have access to.. ".

Answer (score 0):

Create a test user from the facebook page, then use this user to login into your app.

Comment: I have test user created but the Facebook Login page is not showing up..

Comment: I do not know ios, but I think it is an error in your code